# optimize function evaluations caching partial result

Tags: python, caching, scipy, scikits, root-framework

Suppose I have a complex mathematical function with many input parameters `P = [p1, ..., pn]`. Suppose that I can factor the function in blocks, for example:

```
f(P) = f1(p1, p2) * f2(p2, ... pn)
```

and maybe

```
f2(p2, ..., pn) = p2 * f3(p4) + f4(p5, ..., pn)
```

suppose I have to evaluate `f` for many value of `P`, for example I want to find the minimum of `f`. Suppose I have already computed `f(P)` and I need to compute `f(P')` where `P'` is equal to `P` except for `p1`. In this case I don't have to recompute `f2, f3, f4`, but only `f1`.

Is there a library which help me to implement this kind of caching system? I know [RooFit](https://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/roofit), but it is oriented to statistical model, made by blocks. I am looking for something more general. scipy / scikits and similar are preferred, but also c++ libraries are ok. Has this technique a name?

Comment: Why not use a mapping (dictionary)?

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: @ReutSharabani: I would like something more expressive and automatic.

Comment: @Cyphase: python 2 is better

Comment: @RuggeroTurra, I added Python 2 support via a third-party package that backports the Python 3.2 `functools`. I'll also add a simple, self-contained memoization function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can write these function to be pure functions (which means that they always return the same value for the same arguments, and have no side effects), you can use memoization, which is a method for saving results of function calls.

```
try:
    from functools import lru_cache  # Python 3.2+
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    # Python 2 and Python 3.0-3.1
    # Requires the third-party functools32 package
    from functools32 import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def f(arg):
    # expensive operations
    return result

x = f('arg that will take 10 seconds')  # takes 10 seconds
y = f('arg that will take 10 seconds')  # virtually instant
```

For illustration, or if you don't want to use `functools32` on Python < 3.2:

```
def memoize(func):
    memo = {}

    def wrapper(*args):
        if args not in memo:            
            memo[args] = func(*args)
        return memo[args]

    return helper

@memoize
def f(arg):
    # expensive operations
    return result

x = f('arg that will take 10 seconds')  # takes 10 seconds
y = f('arg that will take 10 seconds')  # virtually instant
```